# why $U_{y_1}\cap ....\cap U_{y_n}$? why not $U_{y_1}\cup ....\cup U_{y_n}?$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, separation-axioms

I have some confusion about the statement in Munkras Book

Theorem $26.3$:  Every compact subspace of a  hausdorff space is closed

In the theorem of the proof it is written that  the open set  $V_{y_1} \cup....\cup V_{y_n} $ contain $Y$ and it is disjoint from the open set  **$U_{y_1}\cap ....\cap U_{y_n}$  formed by taking the intersection** of the corresponding  neighbhorhoods of $x_0$

My confusion :  Here the Hausdorff condition ensures  both  $U_y$ and $V_y$ are disjoint  neighbhorhoods  of the point  $x_0$ and $y$

So i think $U_{y_1}\cup ....\cup U_{y_n}$  formed by taking the union  of the corresponding  neighbhorhoods of $x_0$

Im not  getting why  $U_{y_1}\cap ....\cap U_{y_n}$?  why not $U_{y_1}\cup ....\cup U_{y_n}?$

Comment: Without looking at the text (which some of us don't have), it's hard to know what the $V$ and $U$ sets represent exactly. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Note that $V_{y_1}\cup \ldots$ is larger than $V_{y_1}$ so that in order to remain disjoint you certainly want to make $U_{y_1}$ smaller, namely by said intersection. In other words, you won't be able to prove that $V_{y_1}\cup \ldots $ and $U_{y_1}\cup \ldots $ are disjoint

Comment: @CameronWilliams  see [see the page no-163](http://mathcenter.spb.ru/nikaan/2019/topology/4.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\bigcap_{j=1}^nU_{y_j}$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^nV_{y_j}$ are disjoint (since $U_{y_j}$ and $V_{y_j}$ are disjoint for each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$). However, there is no reason why $\bigcup_{j=1}^nU_{y_j}$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^nV_{y_j}$ would be disjoint.